# How to make a button in html shaped as an ellipse with flat sides?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a button which looks like this:
[Required Button Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfM6K.jpg)

However my Button's height and width are in percentage. The only way to do this as far as I could find was border-radius to be half of width (to be specified in pixels) and as my button's width is based on percentage of parent's dimensions i don't the exact value. Putting border-radius as 50% gives a terrible shape. [Button with 50% border radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWDfA.jpg)

I came with a JavaScript but it requires an event:

```
function BorderRadius()
{
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName("LoginButton");
    x[0].style.borderRadius = (x[0].offsetHeight/2).toString()+"px";
}
```

Is there any way to call this JavaScript function automatically or any other solution, using CSS or JavaScript preferably.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why you have set the width and height to be percentages? Seems like an odd thing to do, there may be a better way to handle it.

Comment: @Sarcoma Because its for my college project and the difference in screen sizes has been causing a lot of troubles when using dimensions in pixels and causing the layout to be different than intended

Comment: You might be better off using media queries and creating different sized buttons for a few different screens sizes.

Comment: Though my answer may work, I'd still recommend using media queries to change the heights, it gives you another level of control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though you'll need to test this in a few different browsers setting the `border-radius` to be greater than the button height will give you the rounded corners that you are looking for, at least it does in Firefox.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}
button {
  width:33%;
  height:10%;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>Hello</button>
</div>
```

An alternative might be using Viewport Units instead of percentages. This can be combined with `calc()` and `px` values to give you minimum sizes.

Viewport Units:

```css
button {
  width: calc(100px + 15vw);
  height: calc(20px + 5vw);
  border-radius: calc(10px + 2.5vw);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: The border-radius:999px worked on Chrome too. The Viewport Units concept is unknown to me but I'll soon try to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `border-radius` to fixed value and add `line-height` with same number.

```css
button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<button>Test button</button>
```

Comment: My button's dimensions need to be in percentage. Is there an solution for that?

Comment: See @Sarcoma's answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Sarcoma's answer seems the best solution so far.
There is another way too though.
I just added onload="BorderRadius()" to the body.
It called the function immediately and set the shape.

Comment: You could also use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', BorderRadius, false);` to bind that function to load event without touching the template.

Comment: @MartinAdámek The statement you used seems JQuery to me. If so I haven't started learning it yet. Am still in basics of JavaScript.

Comment: There is no jquery, its plain vanilla JS. jQuery way would be `$(document).on('load', BorderRadius);`. Anyway, where possible, prefer CSS solution as it will be faster.